# Schrödinger representation of the Heisenberg group

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, differential-topology, harmonic-analysis, heisenberg-groups

Let  $\Pi_{\lambda}$  be the the Schrödinger representations of the Heisenberg group $H^n=\Bbb C^n\times\Bbb R$. For $\phi\in L^2(\Bbb R^n)$, we have
$$\Pi_{\lambda} (x,y,t)\phi(\xi)=e^{i\lambda t} e^{i\lambda(x\cdot \xi+\frac{1}{2}x\cdot y)}\phi(\xi+y)
$$ where $x\cdot \xi=\sum^n_{i=1}x_i\xi_i$ and $x\cdot y=\sum^n_{i=1}x_iy_i$ and $(x,y)\in\Bbb R^{n}\times\Bbb R^n$ and $t,\lambda\in\Bbb R$.

Put $\Pi_{\lambda}(X)\phi=\frac{d}{dt}\Bigr\rvert_{t=0}\Big(\Pi_\lambda\big(e^{tX}\big)\phi \Bigr)\ $ and  $\ X_j=\frac{\partial}{\partial x_j}-\frac{1}{2}y_j\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$.
Why do we have:
$$\Pi_{\lambda}(X_j)\phi(\xi)=-i\lambda \xi_j\phi(\xi)\quad?
$$

Comment: no answers for this question!!

Comment: No results for this